# Consuming Web API using javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, model-view-controller

I am trying to consume a live web api found here

```
http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee/1
```

but my code never enters to the success, always going to error.

What am I missing please?

```
<title>ASP.NET Web API</title>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetAllEmployees()
    {
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee/1',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                WriteResponse(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    }
 </script>
 </head>

 <body id="body">

<div>
        <label for="itId">ID:</label>
        <input type="text" id="custId" size="5" />
        <input type="text" id="locId" size="5" />
    <input id="getPerson" type="button" value="Search" onclick="GetAllEmployees();return false;" />

        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="getPersonResult" />
        <p id="item" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What reference libraries do I need to include for both js and jquery?

Or any syntax I am missing?

Comment: What is WriteResponse? I beleive it is a asp.net thing. replace that with alert(data) and see if you are getting anything.

Comment: If the request is failing you need to investigate why. You can see this in (Chrome) the developer console and in the network panel for the request to the url.

Comment: @Caharpuka Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/Index:1
employee/1' from origin 'http://localhost:61446' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: That's strange since I'm able to retrieve this url with XMLHttpRequest and it has a CORS header with Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Comment: I tried consuming a different web api of my own, I installed Cors and added a header, but it is doesn't work

Comment: have you tried to put a cors annotation in your API? [EnableCors(origins: "*", methods: "*", headers: "*")]. Just so you can be sure if your server isn't blocking your connections.
I took you code and debugged locally, didn't had any problems consuming your API.